# Why are there 2 Rumpelstiltskins in Shrek?

Tags: character-identification, shrek, shrek-forever-after, shrek-the-third

In *Shrek the Third*, Rumpelstiltskin appeared in the Poison Apple and had dusk Red hair, a trimmed hat, black facial hair and dull clothing.

But in *Shrek Forever After*, he appears as the main antagonist and has a bigger head, no facial hair and brighter clothing.

Why this? Are they 2 separate people? If so, are they related? Could Rumpelstiltskin be a common name in the Shrek universe?

Comment: Isn't *Shrek Forever After* in an alternate timeline?

Comment: @ZeissIkon that sounds like an answer

Comment: @fez I was asking -- I haven't seen the fourth movie, just a couple trailers and clips.

Comment: @ZeissIkon oh I think it is in an alternate timeline, but Rumpelstiltskin appears _before_ the split

Comment: @fez That guy's always causing trouble...